# Erro com bcrypt em Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem, bcrypt

Em um projeto novo, apos instalar as gemas do Gemfile, quanto tento iniciar o servidor com `rails s` o seguinte erro e apresentado no console :

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.3/bcrypt_ext
```

Comment: Esse erro acontece quando? em qual situação? poderia descrever um pouco mais?

Comment: acontece quando eu dou start no servidor com rails s, logo apos instalar as gemas do gemfile

Comment: Você está usando windows?
Algumas pessoas reportaram esse erro na plataforma windows.

https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142

Informa mais detalhes pra gente ver.

Comment: sim estou usando windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desinstale as gems referentes ao `bcrypt` e reinstale como na última linha abaixo:

```
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
gem uninstall bcrypt
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

Depois, no seu Gemfile, substitua a linha do `bcrypt` por

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'
```

Pare o servidor do Rails e rode `bundle install` e depois pode iniciar o servidor novamente.

Algumas possíveis soluções também podem ser vistas [aqui](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142).